# iOS always returns fail to basic login post requests

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I was trying to do a basic login. My API works fine when I requested through Postman, it returns success as I expected but iOS always returns fail. Below is my iOS code.

Edit: 1-) Server always returns json , such as { "response_message": "fail" }
      2-) Server returns fail with response code 200.

```
NSString *postString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"email=%@&hashed_password=%@",[self.email text],[self.password text]];
//NSLog(@"Post Data: %@",postString);
NSData *postData = [postString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[postData length]];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api/url"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
[request setURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-encoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPBody:postData];

NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
NSDictionary *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization
                          JSONObjectWithData:urlData
                          options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
                          error:&error
                          ];
NSString *response_message = jsonData[@"response_message"];
```

I embedded email and password into url manually and tried to request without postData, it returns success. I checked out email and password inputs, nothing wrong with them. Yet, I'm a newbie and I can't figure out what's wrong with it despite the fact that I noticed there is something wrong with postData.

Comment: When you say it "returns fail", what do you mean? Do you get an error in your NSError object? An HTTP error code in the response? A 200 with the wrong result sent back?

Comment: API returns fail if credentials are not matched, if they are matched it returns success. To be more clear, request hits server and server says no.

Comment: When ever I encounter error with POST methods I check the "content-type". I am not sure whether it is your issue.

Comment: Yes, 200 with wrong result sent back.

Comment: You are writing [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"]; when there is no json data being sent. Please check what type of parameters is going to be sent for the given service

Comment: Server returns json such as { "response_message": "fail" }.

Comment: Let's clarify, because that helps a lot with debugging: iOS doesn't return "fail". Your server returns "fail" (actually it sends a message that it correctly processed your data, with the response it wanted to send you). Your server does that because it doesn't get the data that it expects. Best thing is to google for sample code for this particular server, or better yet for documentation.

Comment: Write your NSData to a file, try to use it with your "Postman" whatever it is. The issue is better to be debugged on the server side because it is server that builds response, iOS framework receives it and creates response object.

Comment: gnasher729, thank you for clarification but if you  mind to read not only the headline but the explanation you could see I already got there.

Comment: A-Live, I'm gonna do that now.

Comment: A debugging proxy like Charles or the burp suite can be helpful in circumstances like these. You can compare your working request with your non-working request and easily see the difference.